# Как в библиотеке на node-vk-bot-api понять что бот в беседе

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, вконтакте, бот

Есть ли в LongPoll API строка отвечающая за беседу?

Я делаю бота и он совершенно не оптимизирован под беседу. Мне надо узнать как это сделать.

Comment: Короче всем спасибо что помогли.

Я нашел такой выход. В Long Poll API, есть такая строчка peer_id

В моем модуле она вызывается вот так: `ctx.message.peer_id`

И если у нее первая цифра "2" то это беседа.

Итог: `if (String(ctx.message.peer_id)[0] == 2)) {Выполнение действий для беседы}`

Answer (score 0):

"peer_id идентификатор назначения.

Для пользователя:
id пользователя.

Для групповой беседы:
2000000000 + id беседы. //От себя добавлю, что плюс это математическое сложение

Для сообщества:
-id сообщества.

целое число, доступен начиная с версии 5.38" из доков